# Using preg_match getting unexpected results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use regular expression, but getting unexpected results:

```
<?php

$a = "Can't you figure it out?";
preg_match("~you (.+) ~", $a, $match);
echo $match[1];

?>
```

**Result:**

figure it

**Need Result:**

figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's happening is that your `.+` sequence is by default *greedy*, so it gobbles up everything to the end of the string. Since you have one more space in your regex after that, it backtracks until it can match that space, hence the final match of "figure it".

you could use the non-greedy quantifer (it eats only one at time and works forward rather than the reverse): `.+?`, or the "word" character (letters/numbers/underscore): `\w+`